# PostgreSQL: create user who can create new roles?

Tags: postgresql

I would like to create a user who can create other roles. 
For example: user "dennis" can create roles.
User "dennis" owns database "main" and can only access this database.
Would it be possible to for "dennis" to create a role, which can access other databases?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-createrole.html

> Be careful with the CREATEROLE privilege. There is no concept of inheritance for the privileges of a CREATEROLE-role. That means that even if a role does not have a certain privilege but is allowed to create other roles, it can easily create another role with different privileges than its own (except for creating roles with superuser privileges). For example, if the role "user" has the CREATEROLE privilege but not the CREATEDB privilege, nonetheless it can create a new role with the CREATEDB privilege. Therefore, regard roles that have the CREATEROLE privilege as almost-superuser-roles.